# Represent number as currenct from paragraph

Tags: javascript, django, currency

On my web page I have an paragraph which looks like this:

```
<p class="article-content mb-1" id="cost"><strong>Cost [Euro]: </strong>1000000</p>
```

Number is always something else (which I read from db and represent using Django forms) and I would like to represent it as currency (in this case 1.000.000).
I tried to get the value with:

```js
function on_load() {
  var a = document.getElementById('cost').value;
  console.log(a)
}
on_load();
```

```html
<p class="article-content mb-1" id="cost"><strong>Cost [Euro]: </strong>1000000</p>
```

but Console output is: 'undefined'. When I get value, I'll use something like

```
(12345.67).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');  // 12,345.67
```

To convert to currency.

Comment: You can render the currency in the Django template. Can you show how you *render* the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` does not have a  value attribute. You can do this to get and format the number using [intl number format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat)

```js
function on_load() {
  const costs = document.querySelector('#cost');
  let number = costs.childNodes[1].textContent;
  costs.childNodes[1].textContent = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE').format(number);
}
on_load();
```

```html
<p class="article-content mb-1" id="cost"><strong>Cost [Euro]: </strong>1000000</p>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Works like a charm, way better this way. Can you just tell me how can I replace 1000000 with new 'var a' data?

Comment: See my update. I assume you want to keep the text